# INotifyPropertyChanged is null with MVVM navigation

Tags: wpf

INotifyPropertyChanged issue may be known and was repeatedly brought up on SO but I think my case is diffrent. I have a ContentControl which changes views depending on ViewModel's type.

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
```

and I have defined many DataTemplates as Resources.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type rightViewModel:CustomViewModel}">
        <rightViews:CustomView/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

And it was working fine until I decided to invoke PropertyChanged event which turned out to be null many times, not always. I kicked off digging and found out that PropertyChanged is null up to moment when any binding is set. I was creating my ViewModels in code-behind and then invoked some actions on that ViewModels and when those actions ended there was no outcome of their work because of PropertyChanged set to null. For instance, i click button, then my viewModels associated with that action is set to CurrentViewModel and viewModel starts doing some actions but View is not rendered yet so, as I said, no binding are detected and therefore PropertyChanged was null. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: *`INotifyPropertyChanged` issue may be known and was repeatedly brought up on SO*... the only `INotifyPropertyChanged` issue discussed on SO is the one that involves new users not using it properly.

Comment: What .net version are you running on ?

Comment: .net version does not matter, 4.5

Comment: I Remember an Old bug in 3.5 where the Binding was not registered to PropertyChanged event . 

the common solution for that was 

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply caused because nothing is listening to the `PropertyChanged` event when you tell it to notify something. If there is no view that has subscribed to handle the event at that stage, then you can simply attach your own listener to it to make it non null.

```
PropertyChanged += SomeViewModel_PropertyChanged;

...

private void SomeViewModel(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate explanation.

Comment: @Sheridan I don't understand why he needs to register the propertychanged him self in his VM , usaully binding is what registers to PropertyChanged event when ithe DataContext is of type INotifyPropertyChanged . What happens here is that it probably adds your handler and the Binding's handler to it's invocation list.

Comment: His problem is that he is using the view model *before* the view has subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event and therefore it is `null`... this is just a little hack to initialise it and get around that.

Comment: My concept was to invoke my actions, which need PropertyChanged event, in Loaded event, but this solution is much better.

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into the details here - the details of raising events are covered in many places - but suffice to say that an event is null until someone subscribes to it. Therefore, when raising an event, you need to first test whether it's null. The common pattern is:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Note how a copy is made of PropertyChanged to avoid threaded race conditions.